# c++ program reading a file

Tags: c++, file

My code :

```
void load_books(){
ifstream myfile(path, ios::in);
if (myfile.fail()){
    cout << "coudln't open file" << "\n\n";
}
else{

    while (myfile){
        myfile >> book1[i].id >> book1[i].title >> book1[i].p_name >> book1[i].p_address >> book1[i].aut_name;
        myfile >> book1[i].aut_nationality >> book1[i].date >> book1[i].status;
        

        cout << book1[i].id << "\ " << book1[i].title << "\ " << book1[i].p_name << "\ " << book1[i].p_address << "\ " << book1[i].aut_name;
        cout << "\ " << book1[i].aut_nationality << "\ " << book1[i].date << "\ " << book1[i].status << endl;
        i++;

    }
    myfile.close();
}

}
```

it should outputs what file contain but i get this in the command

> 111 ahmed yousef lol no yes khaled 15
>
> 222 adas asd sdt huy mjmj mjg2 20
>
> 0       0

the first two lines are correct but I don't know why it outputs the last 2 zeroes (0    0)

Comment: You check before reading.

Comment: @LogicStuff i don't understand !! i'm new at files

Comment: Please consider overloading `>>` for your book class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flesh out [@Bo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36845328/1413395), and answering your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845226/c-program-reading-a-file/36845405#comment61260057_36845328):

> and how i check the status of myfile after each attempted input??!

You can fix your loop like this:

```
void load_books(){
    ifstream myfile(path);
    if (myfile.fail()){
        cout << "coudln't open file" << "\n\n";
    }
    else{
         while (myfile >> book1[i].id >> book1[i].title >> book1[i].p_name 
                       >> book1[i].p_address >> book1[i].aut_name 
                       >> book1[i].aut_nationality >> book1[i].date >> book1[i].status){

            cout << book1[i].id << "\ " << book1[i].title << "\ " << book1[i].p_name << "\ " 
                 << book1[i].p_address << "\ " << book1[i].aut_name << "\ " 
                 << book1[i].aut_nationality << "\ " << book1[i].date << "\ " 
                 << book1[i].status << endl;
            i++;   
        }
    }
}
```

---

Since the chained calls of `std:istream& operator>>(std:istream&, T&)` return the current `std:istream&` reference, the condition in the `while()` loop can be resolved to the `std::basic_ios::operator bool`, and the loop will end as soon the operator evaluates to `false`.

Related reference documentation:

- [`operator>>(std::basic_istream)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2)
- [`std::basic_ios::operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

Answer (score 2):

The condition `while(myfile)` will only stop *after* some input has failed.

At that point you have already printed the zeros from that input attempt.

You have to check the status of `myfile` after each attempted input, to see if it succeeded.

Comment: and how i check the status of ***myfile***  after each attempted input??!

Comment: @david_dd You can chain the two `>>` statements and move them into the loop condition, alternatively `if(!myfile) break;`.